# C# type inference of a generic method type parameter where the method has no arguments

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Given the following generic interface and implementing class:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {
    // U has to be of type T of a subtype of T
    IQueryable<U> Find<U>() where U : T;
}

public class PersonRepository : IRepository<Employee> {

}
```

How could I call the Find method without specififying U?

```
var repository = new EmployeeRepository();
// Can't be done
IQueryable<Employee> people = repository.Find();

// Has to be, but isn't Employee a given in this context?
IQueryable<Employee> people = repository.Find<Employee>();

// Here I'm being specific
IQueryable<Manager> managers = repository.Find<Manager>();
```

In other words, what can be done to get type inference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about writing

```
var people = repository.Find<Employee>();
```

It's saving the same amount of typing but in a different way.

Answer (score 15):

> How could I call the Find method
>   without specififying U?

#### You can't.

Unfortunately C#'s generic method overload resolution doesn't match based on return values.

See Eric Lippert's blog post about it: 
  [C# 3.0 Return Type Inference Does Not Work On Method Groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx)

But one easy way to write this is using `var` keyword.

```
var employees = repository.Find<Employee>();
```